# Changing string values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following list:

`weather = ['sunny', 'foggy', 'cloudy', 22]` that I would like to use it in a 'sche' of spark DataFrame in the follwoing way:

```
sche = "f'status_{weather[0]}_today' string, f'temprature_{weather[3]_today}' int"
```

So that at the end I get 2 columns in my new dataframe as following:
First column: `status_sunny_today`
Second column: `temprature_22_today`

but when I run the code it returns error and does not recognize the format in sche above. If I print just sche, it returns: `f'status_{weather[0]}_today' string, f'temprature_{weather[3]_today}' int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way to use format strings in Python:

```
sche = f"'status_{weather[0]}_today' string, 'temprature_{weather[3]_today}' int"
```

Put `f` before the whole string, not inside the string.